# WP - не перебрасывает в редактор при нажатии "редактировать"

Tags: wordpress

На одном сайте существует такая проблема: при нажатии на ссылку "редактировать запись" http://prntscr.com/q6zveq редактор не открывается, а тебя перебрасывает в админку во все записи. редактор статьи открывается только из самой админки по клику на "изменить" http://prntscr.com/q6zwag

я сравнил обе ссылки, и обнаружил отличие:

это ссылка из админки на редактирование статьи, которая работает:  `/wp-admin/post.php?post=9451&action=edit`

это ссылка из самой статьи по клику на "редактировать запись":  `/wp-admin/post.php?post=9451&amp;action=edit`

как видно во второй ссылке прописан amp; которые ее и ломает. нужно его убрать. **обновлять wordpress нельзя**.

я сначала думал мб дело в каком то из плагинов, отключал все, но это ничего не дало.

скорее всего нужно покопаться в коде вордпресса, где то в папке /wp-admin/ , и если моя догадка верна мб кто то подскажет файл отвечающий за это меню http://prntscr.com/q6zveq , возможно там я найду выход исправляющий проблему со ссылой.

удалось найти

```
&& $edit_post_link = get_edit_post_link( $current_object->ID ) )
        {
            $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
                'id' => 'edit',
                'title' => $post_type_object->labels->edit_item,
                'href' => $edit_post_link
            ) );
```

но это ничего не даёт мне, кроме переменной $edit_post_link

---

**UPDATE**

обновление wordpress не принесло результатов, значит дело не в ядре движка. проблема сохраняется и при смене шаблона на стандартный + отключении всех плагинов.
не знаю что и думать.

Comment: В коде водрпресса копаться точно не только не нужно, но и нельзя Хоть бы голову включал - у всех работает, а у тебя нет. Или уже накопался и пополомал или плагины/темы

Comment: сайт не мой, старый, попросили посмотреть. что там делалось до меня неизвестно. изменений лично я никаких не вносил. а подобные вашим комментарии не несут никакой пользы, поэтому если помочь ничем не можете то лучше не мешайте.

Comment: Переключитесь на дефолтную тему wp и посмотрите останется ли проблема. Но если все таки вносились изменения в ядро WP, то выкачиваете оригинальную версию с сайта wp и сравниваете с вашей - смотрите кто что там менял.

Comment: обновил wordpress и все плагины. проблема не ушла. переключился на стандартную тему - тоже самое http://prntscr.com/q7g065

Answer (score 0):

Вот в чём была проблема!

В wp-config.php `define( 'CUSTOM_TAGS', true );` ,закомментировав этот код ошибка устранилась.